# Get XpsDocument from FixedDocumentSequence

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

I converted an `XpsDocument` to `FixedDocumentSequence` (in a converter) using `myXpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence();` method .

Now I need the `XpsDocument.Uri` in code behind to release its file lock :

```
System.IO.Packaging.PackageStore.GetPackage(xpsUri).Close();
System.IO.Packaging.PackageStore.RemovePackage(xpsUri);
```

**And problem is : How  can I access the XpsDocument (or its Uri) in Code behind.**

Comment: Why not to dispose it after converting to FixedDocumentSequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of disposing it from code behind, you should `dispose it as soon as you get it converted to FixedDocumentSequence` may be inside converter only since no need to hold onto it once it gets converted to fixed document sequence.